# Running a Python script for files in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

There are 15 text files in a folder and I am trying to extract certain parts of each file and output them to a new file.

I am able to extract each file individually by just changing the file name and append each file to the output file but this means copying the same code 15 times and just changing the file name each time.

```
import glob,os

lst = []
filelist=glob.glob  ('/C:/Users/bridaly/Documents/PythonTest/Python_Test_ENdata_3080_v20150914/input/*')

for file in filelist:

    if os.path.isfile(file):

        for line in filelist:
            line = line.strip()
            if not (
                line.startswith("APPEND") or line.startswith("_") or
                line.startswith("SAP") or line.startswith("~") or
                line.startswith("INCLUDE")  or line.startswith("ABAP")
                or line.strip() == "" or line.startswith("Field") or
                line.startswith("Short")
                ) :     

                y=line.replace('     ',' ')
                #print(y)

                z = y.replace('X','')
                #print(z)

                w = "|".join(z.split())
                #print(w)

                x = w.split("|",3)[:4]
                #print(x)
                x.insert(0,'./input/01BKPF')
                #print(x)

                if len(x) >=4:


                    t = [s.replace('|',' ') for s in x]
                    #print(t)
                    print("|".join(t))
                    lst.append("|".join(t))
#Output Script

output_file = open('Output_Final.txt', 'w')
for l in lst:
    output_file.write(l)
    output_file.write('\n')
output_file.close()
```

"""

The output should extract what's written in the code but for each file and append it to the output file. I have gotten the correct output by copying the code 15 times but I just want to use it once as it is more efficient.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "copying the same code 15 times and just changing the file name each time"? If I am understanding this question right, then you already have the path to all of the text files in the directory, and you should just be able to iterate over it.

Comment: I want to run this same script for every text file in the folder and the output should print it to the new text file.

Comment: So, you have the path to all the files in the folder, so is there a reason you do not want to iterate over using the array of the file paths? If you need to do different operations depending on a file, you can just use a `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = glob.glob('path')
for file in files:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)
    print(file_name)
```

you can iterate for each file